# How do I parse a CSV file, to make it easily accessable for tableView?

Tags: swift, xcode, csv, parsing, swift5

I wrote a CSV file that contains a set of items by row. I used a class like so to form the CSV file, here is the code for creating the file:

```
class SymptomData: NSObject {
var symptom: String = ""
var severity: String = ""
var comment: String = ""
var timestamp: String = ""
}

var symptom_data = [SymptomData]()
var symptomData: SymptomData!

func writeTrackedSymptomValues(symptom: String, comment: String, time: String, timestamp: String) {
    symptomData = SymptomData()
    for _ in 0..<5 {
        symptomData.symptom = symptom
        symptomData.severity = self.severity
        symptomData.comment = comment
        symptomData.timestamp = timestamp
        symptom_data.append(symptomData!)
    }

    createCSV()
}

    var logFile: URL? {
        guard let documentsDirectory = FileManager.default.urls(for: .documentDirectory, in: .userDomainMask).first else { return nil }
        let fileName = "symptom_data.csv"
        return documentsDirectory.appendingPathComponent(fileName)
    }

    func createCSV() {
        guard let logFile = logFile else {
            return
        }

        guard let data = ("\(symptomData.symptom),\(symptomData.severity),\(symptomData.comment),\(symptomData.timestamp)\n").data(using: String.Encoding.utf8) else { return }

        if FileManager.default.fileExists(atPath: logFile.path) {
            if let fileHandle = try? FileHandle(forWritingTo: logFile) {
                fileHandle.seekToEndOfFile()
                fileHandle.write(data)
                fileHandle.closeFile()
            }
        } else {
            var csvText = "Symptom,Severity,Comment,Time\n"


                 let newLine = "\(symptomData.symptom),\(symptomData.severity),\(symptomData.comment),\(symptomData.timestamp)\n"
                 csvText.append(newLine)


             do {
                try csvText.write(to: logFile, atomically: true, encoding: String.Encoding.utf8)

             } catch {
                 print("Failed to create file")
                 print("\(error)")
             }
             print(logFile ?? "not found")
        }
    }
```

The CSV file looks like this:

[image: CSV File]

Now I would like to read the file, and add each row to my table view. Ideally, I would like to be able to access each row easily like so:

```
row0.symptom = symptomData[0].symptom
row0.comment = symptomData[0].comment
```

etc. But I am not sure how to parse the data back into my class, I would also like it like this so that I can reorder them by timestamp.

Here is how I am parsing the data so far:

```
func readCSV() {
    guard let logFile = logFile else {
        return
    }

    if FileManager.default.fileExists(atPath: logFile.path) {
        if let fileHandle = try? FileHandle(forWritingTo: logFile) {
            fileHandle.seekToEndOfFile()
            fileHandle.readDataToEndOfFile()
            fileHandle.closeFile()
            print("symptom_data exists")
            do {
                let file = try String(contentsOf: logFile)
                let rows = file.components(separatedBy: .newlines)
                for row in rows {
                    let fields = row.replacingOccurrences(of: "\"", with: "").components(separatedBy: ",")

                    print(fields)

                }
            } catch {
                print(error)
            }

        }
    } else {
         print("No symptom_data File.")
    }
}
```

This prints this:

```
 ["Symptom", "Severity", "Comment", "Time"]
 ["Anxiety", "Severe", "test", "1592333677"]
 ["Anxiety", "Mild", "test2", "1592333686"]
 ["Fatigue", "Mild", "test3", "1592160840"]
 ["Electric shock sensations (Brain Zaps)", "Mild", "", "1592333820"]
 ["Anxiety", "Severe", "", "1592336985"]
```

How can I get each row into a class or struct so I can easily add it to the table view, or is there a better way to do it?

Comment: Is CSV mandatory? There are much more suitable text formats.

Comment: It's not mandatory, open to better ideas.

Comment: JSON or Property List. Both are supported very efficiently and you can use light-weight structs instead of *heavy* classes.